# ParametrizedType - empty array as result of getActualTypeArguments()

Tags: java, reflection

I'm testing code with reflections and I have a problem with reproduce one `if` statement in my code, probably because I don't understand correctly how the method works.

```java
class TestClass {
    public Collection<TestField> field;
}
...
ParameterizedType type = (ParameterizedType) TestClass.class.getField("field").getGenericType();
```

Now, I am looking for a `FieldType`, for which the `getActualTypeArguments()` method will return an **EMPTY** `Type[]` array.

Based on [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html):

> Note that in some cases, the returned array be empty. This can occur if this type represents a non-parameterized type nested within a parameterized type.

Unfortunately, I have a problem with understanding this fragment, so I can't design a class that will fulfill it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Section 4.5 of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5) has a footnote about this:

> A parameterized type may be an parameterization of a generic class or interface which is nested. For example, if a non-generic class `C` has a generic member class `D<T>`, then `C.D<Object>` is a parameterized type. And if a generic class `C<T>` has a non-generic member class `D`, then the member type `C<String>.D` is a parameterized type, even though the class `D` is not generic.

So `C<String>.D` is also a `ParameterizedType`! This is what the documentation of `getActualTypeArguments` was referring to. And according to the docs, `getActualTypeArguments` would return an empty array for `C<String>.D`. Here is an example:

```
class Foo<T> {
    class Bar {

    }
}
public class Main {

    public Foo<Integer>.Bar bar;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ParameterizedType type = (ParameterizedType) Main.class.getField("bar").getGenericType();

        // this prints 0
        System.out.println(type.getActualTypeArguments().length);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the link, they helped both to solve the problem and understand it.